# Is the centre of Italy still at risk of earthquakes?

Tags: seismology

I am working on a project which involves taking over a business based in Italy. It is a small village situated near Rieti (Sabina Hills) called Casperia and I am wondering if it is on a fault line? Is there a risk of having more quakes in the centre of Italy? It's a business in the tourism industry, so it is very important for me to find out about the risks before I go ahead... Any suggestions welcome.

Many thanks for your time.

Adeline

Comment: Look at the last map on this [website](https://www.mapsofworld.com/thematic-maps/earthquake/italy.html).

Answer (score 4):

The Italian Civil Defense's [map of earthquake risk zones](http://www.eurometeo.com/english/read/doc_zone-sismiche) shows Rieti in at *best* Zone 2, "Medium-high seismicity, quite strong earthquakes possible", and near or in Zone 1, "High or catastrophic seismicity, strong earthquakes possible".

The map of [recent earthquakes in Rieti](https://earthquaketrack.com/it-07-rieti/recent) shows regular earthquake activity. Last year [an earthquake killed hundreds in Rieti](https://earthquake-report.com/2016/08/24/very-strong-earthquake-central-italy-on-august-24-2016-2/).

There was a famous [long legal case](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2015/11/italy-s-supreme-court-clears-l-aquila-earthquake-scientists-good) in Italy over earthquake predictions and warnings.